# Change tab navigator name and header

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm new in react native and I created a bottom tab navigator. I have 3 menus: Home, Tenants, and WorkOrders. How can I change the WorkOrders to display the button name and header as "Work Orders" instead of "WorkOrders"?

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home,
    Tenants,
    WorkOrders
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
      return {
        headerTitle: routeName
      };
  }
});

const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    MainTabNavigator
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            name="md-menu"
            size={30}
          />
        )
      };
    }
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Menu: {
    screen: MainStackNavigator
  }
});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Main: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ...,
  WorkOrders: {
    screen: WorkOrders,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Work Orders'
      // You can check more options here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#navigationoptions-for-screens-inside-of-the-navigator
    }
  }
},{
  // BottomTabNavigatorConfig
})
```

You can do the same with other react-navigation's API

Comment: Thanks it works for button title, but I can't change the header. Even thought I enter headerTitle: 'Work Orders', it still showing 'WorkOrders'. I think it is because the BottomTabNavigatorConfig rewrite the headerTitle rules